# Korean address system

Tags: user-interface, street-address

I am trying to create a address form for south korean people. I don't know korean language. So, Can someone provide me example address forms. Also, are there any trick to validate this form? (required, lenght, special regex etc.)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Old thread but here it is:
You will need Street Number, Street Address, Province, City, Zip Code.
The order goes like this:
City, Province, Street Name, Street Number, and apartment # if any, then Zip Code.